# Finding the PDF of a function $e^{2X}$

Tags: probability

I'm working on old exam papers, and came across an exercise, which I can't quite wrap my head around. The exercise goes as follows:

Let $X \sim Exponential(3)$ and let $Y=e^{2X}$

I was then asked to compute $E[X]=3$, which I have done.

Now I am asked to find the PDF of $Y$. From what I've read around the web, and in my textbook, I need to produce the CDF of $Y$, and then differentiate that, to get to the PDF I'm looking for.

$$
\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leq y)\\
&=P(e^{2X}\leq y)
\end{align}
$$

I can't get any further than that, trying to find the CDF, because I'm not sure of how to assign values to $y$, or if there is something I've completely misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go on by stating  that $F_Y(y)=0$ if  $y\leq1$ and for $y>1$ we have:$$F_Y(y)=P(2X\leq\ln y)=F_X(1/2\ln y)=1-e^{-3/2\ln y}=1-y^{-3/2}$$

Then the PDF can be found by differentiating:$$f_Y(y)=\frac32y^{-\frac{5}{2}}\text{ if }y>1$$