# PDF of $Y=e^{2X}$ given X~exp(3)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the random variable X∼exp(3). And let $Y=e^{2X}$.

Find the PDF of Y.

---

I know by properties of exp distribution that the PDF of $f_X(x)$ is given by $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
 3e^{-3x}; & \text{ if, }  x > 0 \\
 0; & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

The way I approched the problem is by first trying to find the CDF of Y and then taking the derivative to get the PDF of Y.

This is a exercise on a previous exam so I know the result and I'm getting a wrong one. I think I'm having troubles finding the CDF. This is what I've tried

$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y)=P(e^{2X}\le y)=P(X\le \frac{ln(y)}{2})$

So I have the upper limit and the lower limit of the integral is 1, as $e^{2\cdot 0}$ is 1 and that is the lowest that $x$ gets.

I then integrate the the whole thing to find the CDF.

$\int_{1}^{\frac{ln(y}{2}} 3e^{-3X} \ dx$

But I'm doing something wrong, because it's suppose to give me the result of $\frac{3}{2}y^\frac{-5}{2}$, for $y>1$

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2792698/75923) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2792899/75923).

Answer (score 0):

Actually $X$ can go to zero, so the correct lower bound for $x$ is $0$ instead of $1$, giving us:
$$F_Y(y) = \int_{0}^{(\ln y)/2} 3e^{-3x} \ \mathrm dx = 1 - y^{-3/2}$$

Therefore:
$$f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y) = \frac32y^{-5/2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain why X can go to zero?

Comment: $X$ is exponentially distributed, so its pdf has a support over $[0;\infty)$ @Sirmimer